# variable co-efficient 2nd order linear ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a variable co-efficient 2nd order linear ODE by using a transformation for the independent variable:

$y'' + \frac{2}{4x} y' + \frac{9}{4x} y = 0$ with transformation $t = \sqrt{x}$

so i have setup $t' = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ and $t'' = \frac{-1}{4 
\sqrt[3]{x}}$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt} \frac{dt}{dx}$ which is just the chain rule

$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

now $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx} (\frac{dy}{dt} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}})$ - equation (1)

$= \frac{dy}{dt} \frac{-1}{4 \sqrt[3]{x}} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \frac{d}{dx} (\frac{dy}{dt})$. Then i let $u = \frac{dy}{dx}$

$\frac{d}{dx} (\frac{dy}{dt}) = \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{du}{dt} \frac{dt}{dx}$ which is using the chain rule

then, $\frac{du}{dt} \frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{dy}{dt} (\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}})$

substituting back to equation (1) gives: $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{dy}{dt} \frac{-1}{4 \sqrt[3]{x}} - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}(\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}})$.

Assuming what i have done is correct, do i then substitute this expression for $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ into the original ODE? any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \frac{2}{4x} \frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{9}{4x} y = 0 \text{ with transformation } t = \sqrt{x}$$
$\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{2t}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{1}{2t}\frac{dy}{dt}$

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}= (\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dy}{dx}))\frac{dt}{dx}=(\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{2t}\frac{dy}{dt}) )\frac{1}{2t}=-\frac{1}{4t^3}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{1}{4t^2}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$
$$(-\frac{1}{4t^3}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{1}{4t^2}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2})+\frac{2}{4t^2}(\frac{1}{2t}\frac{dy}{dt})+\frac{9}{4t^2}y=0$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+9y=0$$
$$y=c_1\cos(3t)+c_2\sin(3t)$$
$$y=c_1\cos(3\sqrt{x})+c_2\sin(3\sqrt{x})$$

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $$\frac{dy(x)}{dx}=\frac{dt}{dx}\frac{dy(t)}{dt}$$ we get
$$y''(t)+9y(t)=0$$ and $$y''(x)=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{dy(t)}{dt}+\left(\frac{dt}{dx}\right)^2\frac{d^2y(t)}{dt^2}$$